# Export json from python to C# file encoding issue

Tags: c#, python, json, readfile, file-encodings

I have a python script that generates a json file that is further used on a C# application. This is the code creating the export:

```
def put(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf8')
```

Then in the C# application I attempt to read it the following way:

```
public static string readFile(string filename)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        return r.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

//different file
string json_result = funcs.readFile(out_file);
VirtualMachine newvm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json_result);
```

The problem is `json_result` contains the characters `\r\n` at each line break and fails to Deserialize the json.

I tried to check the encoding produced by the python script and according to SublimeText is `u'Undefined'`

How can I make python correctly encode the file for C# or make C# load it with the right encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I imagine is happening is that you are on a Windows system, and the python script's `open` command is automatically making newlines ends with `\r\n` and the C# reader does not expect them.

One way to fix this is to write to the file as binary instead of as text:

```
def put(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf-8"))
```

However the issue may also inside of the `JSON` library itself while using `indent`, which could be fixed by either removing the argument (but I assume you want it pretty for a reason) or edit the `JSON` string after generating it and do a replace `/r/n` with `/n` before writing to the file.